# Google maps marker missing API v3

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have a google map API **v3** embed in my website with a custom marker. And as you know, you can click in the google logo for see a bigger version of it in the *maps.google* site.

My problem begin when you click in the link wich lead you to maps.google site, because you can only see the map area keeping the coordinates, but the marker is **missing**.

I just want keep my marker in the map when I click the google's logo. Is a little bit annoying for some clients being lost in a map without the marker.

Default google code is not allowing it. What should I add to my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() 
{
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.348186,-3.701099),
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapa"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: map.getCenter(),
    map: map,
    title: 'YANBOR AUTOGAS'
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(16);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
var center = map.getCenter();
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
map.setCenter(center); 
});
</script>
```

Thanks you in advance.

Jorge

Comment: The link redirects you to the Google Maps website. I don't understand what this has to do with your code. You want the marker to also show up in Google Maps site?

Comment: Yes, I want keep the marker in google maps site. My code is working 100%, but i dont know how to do it (keep marker in google's site)

Comment: make a [feature-request](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry). It's not allowed to modify this link.

Comment: So, there is no way to do it?

Comment: If I understand properly problem of your customers is small map which is not shown over whole window. Why don't you enable them, for example, resize button which will resize viewport of map or open a new window with your code so you can control it?

Comment: +1 for the above comment. Or provide a custom link to google maps, other than the logo one.

Comment: Well, at the moment i dont know what im going to do. Anyway, thanks you really!